# How to seed Identity in .NET Core 8 CleanArchitecture

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi, clean-architecture, .net-8.0

I am learning Clean Architecture.
FirstLy I create a MVC Project.
Then I Create Some Class Library as you can See in the pictures>

Then I move identity to my `Infrastructure.Identity` project.
Separate IdentityDBContext (In Infastructure.Identity Project) and ApplicationDBContext (In Persitain Project)

[image]

The project has been upload to here for more investigate:
https://github.com/nguyentuananh921/Learning.git

Now I want to seed somedata in to Database but I failed after alot of searching.Please help.

Comment: could you pls explain more about what you did/which tutorial you followed/etc....